# Syntax error in python mercurial plugin

Tags: python, mercurial

I just installed this "checkfiles" plugin and it has a syntax error.  I don't know Python, but I've tried a few things and can't figure it out.  I'm wondering if someone else could take a peek and see if anything stands out.  It's the very last line of the code below:

```
   if self.opt_all:
        self.check_diffs = False

    if self.checked_exts == '""':
        self.ui.debug('checkfiles: checked extensions: (all text files)\n')
    else:
        self.ui.debug('checkfiles: checked extensions: %s\n' % ' '.join(self.checked_exts))

    self.ui.debug('checkfiles: ignored extensions: %s\n' % ' '.join(self.ignored_exts))
    self.ui.debug('checkfiles: ignored files: %s\n' % ' '.join(self.ignored_files))
    self.ui.debug('checkfiles: check diffs only: %r\n' % self.check_diffs)
    self.ui.debug('checkfiles: use spaces: %r\n' % self.use_spaces)

    if ctx:
        self.set_changectx(ctx)

def set_changectx(self, ctx):
    self.ctx = ctx

    if self.opt_all:
        modified, added, removed, deleted, unknown, ignored, clean = self.repo.status(clean=True)
        self.files = modified + added + clean # we can't get filecontext for unknown files
    else:
        self.files = ctx.files() if ctx else []  #THIS IS LINE 120
```

*** failed to import extension checkfiles from /scripts/mercurial-extensions/checkfiles/checkfiles.py: invalid syntax (checkfiles.py, line 120)

Comment: OS, OS version, Python version?

Comment: Linux... but not sure about Python version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last line is correct modern Python.
It contains a conditional expression which was added in Python 2.5.
So, I think your Hg must be running Python 2.4 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Replace line 120 with

```
self.files = ctx and ctx.files() or []
```

which is the Python 2.4 compatible way to do

```
self.files = ctx.files() if ctx else []
```